# Filament Manage Related with hasMany and hasMany with Repeater

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I will write my problem

I have 3 tables : "Process", "Units" and "UnitsItems"

```
process
    id - integer
    name - string
    number_process - float
    hasMany
        units - process_id
```

```
units
    id - integer
    name - string
    process_id - integer
    address - string
    hasMany
        items_units - units_id
```

```
items_units
    id - integer
    name - string
    value - float
    units_id - integer
```

The problem is that when I create a new unit, I must add 1 (or more) itemsunits that are connected to a unit, through the "repeater". A unit can be linked to 1 or many unit items. But when I try to add some unit items it has the following error.

[image: Error Code]

I followed how the documentation says, but I couldn't.

My Code:

Process.php

```php
class Process extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'process';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name','number_process',
    ];

    public function units(){
        return $this->hasMany(Units::class, 'process_id');
    }
}
```

Units.php

```php
class Units extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'units';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name','address','process_id'
    ];

    public function itemsUnits(){
        return $this->hasMany(ItemsUnits::class, 'units_id');
    }
}
```

ItemsUnits.php:

```php
class ItemsUnits extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'items_units';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name','value','units_id'
    ];

}
```

UnitsRelationManager.php :

```php
class UnitsRelationManager extends ManageRelatedRecords
{
    protected static string $resource = ProcessResource::class;
    protected static string $relationship = 'units';

    public function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                    ->required(),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('address')
                    ->required()
                    ->maxLength(150),
                Forms\Components\Section::make('Items')
                    ->schema([
                        Forms\Components\Repeater::make('Items')
                            ->relationship('itemsUnits')->label("")
                            ->schema([
                                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                                    ->required(),
                                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('value')
                                    ->required(),
                            ])->minItems(1)
                    ]),


            ]);
    }

    public function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->recordTitleAttribute('name')
            ->columns([
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('name'),
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->headerActions([
                Tables\Actions\CreateAction::make(),
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
                Tables\Actions\DeleteAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ])
            ->emptyStateActions([
                Tables\Actions\CreateAction::make(),
            ]);
    }
}
```